# How to apply Vim color scheme to all users?

Tags: vim, colors

I installed a new color scheme for my vim editor and have put an entry in ~/.vimrc to start vim everytime with this color scheme. But the problem is it applies to vim sessions opened ONLY with sudo. If I do a vim as regaular user I dont see the color scheme applied.

I have the following entries in both places

1. Location 1: `/usr/share/vim/vimrc`
2. Location 2: `~/.vimrc`

---

```
set t_Co=256
let g:seoul256_background = 233
colo seoul256
```

I dont understand why the color scheme is applied only to sudo user.

Answer (score 1):

May be you have placed the colorscheme file only for root (which I think resides usually in `/root/.vim/colors`).

You can try to copy the colorscheme from there to `~/.vim/colors/` (i.e user's home directory) and then see if it works.

Also there is a Q&A site dedicated to [vi and vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/), so have a look at https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2782/how-can-i-create-my-own-colorscheme